# HDFS not accessible from a java application

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

I have a clouder quickstart container and I try to get the list of file under HDFS using a java application;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HdfsListing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Configuration  configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.set("fs.default.name","hdfs://172.17.0.2:9000");

        FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(configuration);
        Path path=new Path("hdfs://172.17.0.2:9000/user");
        FileStatus[] fsl=fs.listStatus(path);
        for(FileStatus f:fsl) System.out.println("=======>"+f.getPath().getName());
    }
}
```

when I run that code I get the following messages in the console

```
7790 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - The ping interval is 60000 ms.
7792 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Connecting to /172.17.0.2:9000
32439 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client  - Retrying connect to server: 172.17.0.2/172.17.0.2:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
...
```

the hosts file under hadoop

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost
#::1    localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0        ip6-localnet
#ff00::0        ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1        ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2        ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2      quickstart.cloudera quickstart
```

Comment: 1. Are you able to do `hdfs dfs -ls /`? 2. Is the java app running inside the sandbox?

Comment: yeah I'm able to do hdfs dfs -ls / command which means that the namenode is running . java app is running under windows

Comment: I assume sandbox IP is not reachable from your windows host. Where did you run your hdfs command?

Comment: I run it  in the cloudera container

Comment: how can I do so ?

Comment: I think It's workin now, by creating a new container with -p 8020:8020 option and replaced the 127.17.0.2 ip with localhost in the java code.